# Removing commas between tags in Squaresapce

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Helping a friend out with her Squarespace site, and she wants to hide a series of categories/tags from her blog posts, except for the first three. I was able to do that easily with CSS with an nth-of-type selector. The problem is, Squarespace has injected (I'm assuming through PHP) a comma after every tag, so it looks like

CATEGORY, CATEGORY, CATEGORY,,,,,,

Because it's Squarespace, I'm unable to get to the PHP file without entering the developer mode which would bar her from easily editing her site on her own.

Here's what the code looks like:

```html
<span class="entry-category" id="yui_3_17_2_8_1474308570683_4842">
<a href="/?category=COLLABORATIONS" class="entry-morefrom-link" rel="tag">COLLABORATIONS</a>
,
<a href="/?category=Dress" class="entry-morefrom-link" rel="tag">Dress</a>, <a href="/?category=FASHION" class="entry-morefrom-link" rel="tag" id="yui_3_17_2_8_1474308570683_4979">FASHION</a>
,
<a href="/?category=HAIR" class="entry-morefrom-link" rel="tag">HAIR</a>
,
<!-- etc. etc. -->
</span>
```

CSS and JS/jQuery are the only options I have here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: try this $('.entry-category').text().replace(',', '');

Comment: as long as there are no commas in the a tags that should work

Comment: Maybe look into this? https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205814218 it shows setting limits on tags. Not sure about categories. Also, why not have your friend not add that many categories in the first place?

Comment: Because you are saying that the site has injected this, it will be hard to find out what is causing it my friend. we can't see any functions or code that is responsible for this, and any solution will be "a shot in the dark". I would seriously  consider transferring the site to wix. (wix.com).

Comment: Thanks @AfnanNazir, but no luck.

Comment: @nerdlyist — I know, right? Seems like the logical solution. But she's a fashion blogger and relies heavily on the integration between her blog and this other platform called Bloglovin which only imports categories, not tags.

Here's the site, if anyone wants to Inspect it: http://aikaslovecloset.com. The issue is occurring on the homepage, though I've removed the nth-of-type CSS until I can figure out how to lose the commas.

Answer (score 0):

Got a hold of a friend who helped me figure out the issue. Part of it was that I was running an old jQuery reference instead of 2.1.1 or anything remotely recent. The code we were able to get to work was

```
$('.entry-category').map(function(val, i) {
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(/,/g, ' ');
})
```

Thanks for the input, guys.